# Get Div value when clicked using AJAX

Tags: php, html, jquery, ajax

```
<div id = "Class" class = "Class_ticket" onclick = "caller()" value = "1">
```

I am trying to get `value` of `div` where ID is `Class` when `Div` is clicked.

```
function caller(){
          $.ajax({
              url: "test.php",
              type: "get",
              data: {
                Class_info: $('#Class').val()
              }
          }).done(function(data) {
              $('#Result').text(data);
              alert(data);
        });
      }
```

Looks like it isn't reading the value of `Div` when clicked. Am I using AJAX wrongly?

`test.php`

```
<?php
  $a = $_GET['Class_info'];
  echo($a);
?>
```

Comment: A div does not have a value, so you will have to do `$('#Class').attr("value")`

Comment: `div` tag not have an `value` attribute. you can use `data` attribute as `data-value` in `div`. Tag like `input` have `value` attribute.

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen Thanks for help. Just wonder, is it common to use `Div` to replace `Button`?

Comment: People do all sorts of things but you should use A for links and BUTTON / INPUT+SUBMIT/BUTTON for form submitters.

Comment: *use a div to replace button* - no, you should always use the correct element for the correct scenario.  If you need an element to click that doesn't navigate away, then use a `button`.  It's needed for accessibility, such as screen readers.   Most likely you just need some css for your button.

Answer (score 0):

`div` tag dont have value attribute. So you can use `$('#Class').attr('value')`;
check snippet below..

```js
function caller(){
  alert($('#Class').attr('value'));
  $.ajax({
      url: "test.php",
      type: "get",
      data: {
        Class_info: $('#Class').attr('value')
      }
  }).done(function(data) {
      $('#Result').text(data);
      alert(data);
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id = "Class" class = "Class_ticket" onclick = "caller()" value = "1">test</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this little trick:

```html
<div id "" class="Class_ticket" onclick="caller()" value="1">
    <input type="hidden" value="1" id="Class" />
</div>
```

note that the input is hidden!

And here is your ajax:

```js
function caller() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "test.php",
        type: "get",
        data: {
            Class_info: $('#Class').val()
        }
    }).done(function(data) {
        $('#Result').text(data);
        alert(data);
    });
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
function caller(){
          $.ajax({
              url: "test.php?Class_info=test",
              type: "get",
              data: {
                Class_info: $('#Class').val()
              }
          }).done(function(data) {
              $('#Result').text(data);
              alert(data);
        });
      }
```

I added `?info=test` which in theory PHP should be able to take

if PHP takes the value, then instead of test put a variable containing the desired value